# A system of 2 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

During a physics problem, I have encountered a set of 2 equations and after trying to solve them for quite a while, I start to thing there may be no solution. Am I missing something really easy?

$$ (1) A_{n}\cos\left(\sqrt{\lambda}_{n}R\right)+B_{n}\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda}_{n}R\right)=0$$

$$(2)A_{n}\cos\left(\sqrt{\lambda}_{n}\left(R+\pi\right)\right)+B_{n}\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda}_{n}\left(R+\pi\right)\right)=0$$

I'm searching for $\lambda_n$ that solves both equations, but nothing seems to work. I can choose any values I want for $A_n$ and $B_n$, I tried taking one of them to be zero but it doesn't help.

Comment: is it supposed to be not equal to zero for all R?

Comment: It is supposed to be equal, I edited (the ! was confusing I guess).

Comment: Notice that if $\sqrt{\lambda_n}=2k, \ k\in\mathbb Z$, then the second equation is equivalent to the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your set of equations in terms of matrices, it has the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}R) & \sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}R)\\
\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}(R+\pi)) & \sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}(R+\pi))\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A_n\\ B_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
In order to have non-trivial solutions (i.e. $A_n, B_n$ not both zero), a necessary and sufficient condition is the $2\times 2$ matrix is degenerate and has zero determinant. i.e.

$$\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}R)\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}(R+\pi)) - 
\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}R)\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}(R+\pi)) = 0\tag{*1}$$
Compare this with the trigonometry identity:

$$\sin(a - b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) - \sin(b)\cos(a)$$

One find $(*1)$ is equivalent to
$$\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}(R + \pi) - \sqrt{\lambda_n}R) = \sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}\pi) = 0$$
Since $\sin(x) = 0$ if and only if $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, to have non-trival solutions, you need
$$\sqrt{\lambda_n} = k \iff \lambda_n = k^2$$
for some non-negative integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$$A_n\sin(X)+B_n\cos(X)=0\Rightarrow \frac{A_n\sin(X)+B_n\cos(X)}{\sqrt{A_n^2+B_n^2}}=\sin(\theta+X)=0$$ where $\cos(\theta)=\dfrac{A_n}{\sqrt{n^2+B_n^2}}$ and $\sin(\theta)=\dfrac{B_n}{\sqrt{A_n^2+B_n^2}}$.

Consecuently $$\theta +X=?$$ Similarly you can get $$\theta +Y=?$$